# SQL Statement throws exception with autoincrement

Tags: sqlite, auto-increment

I am trying to create a table in an sqlite database with the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (_id)
);
```

It throws the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error
at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.throwex(NativeDB.java:397)
at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._exec(Native Method)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.executeUpdate(JDBC3Statement.java:116)
at de.marcofriedmann.dbtest.DBController.createTables(DBController.java:64)
at de.marcofriedmann.dbtest.Main.main(Main.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

I am not able to find a syntax error. If i omit the auto_increment, everything works fine.

Any hints?

Comment: There is no underscore in `AUTO INCREMENT`

Comment: thank you. it works now if i dont use "not null" on the same column. But when I  use the following statement "INSERT INTO contacts 
 (surname,
name) VALUES
 ('Friedmann',
'Marco')", the id shows "NULL". Shouldnt it show an INT?

Comment: You probably want to declare the `_id` column as `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, which will make it an alias for the `rowid`.

Comment: i tried this too. but the id still shows "NULL". And is the declaration not the same as PRIMARY KEY (_id) in the last row?

Answer (score -2):

The MS SQL Server uses the IDENTITY keyword to perform an auto-increment feature.

In the example above, the starting value for IDENTITY is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each new record.

Source: [CREATE TABLE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

The underscore is only used with mySQL.